# Iphone 4 - Is it possible to capture a camera event (takePicture) in a background application

Tags: iphone, ios4

Is it possible to have a background background app. notified in case of a camera event generated by the native OS app?

Comment: I sure hope there isn't, I'd be too afraid to ever take a picture with my iPhone again.

Answer (score 0):

The app sandbox prevents apps from knowing what other apps (including the Camera app) are doing except via explicit communication (e.g. registered URL handlers, shared VOIP network connection, etc.), at least under the stock OS when sticking to apps that comply with the SDK agreement.

Comment: It is possible in Android, where I have implemented a no. of features where receiving notifications to any other app. like camera/incoming call/sms/mms is possible. I wish Apple offered similar features. Does it at least provide a file system listener? If the native camera app stores an image in a certain directory, can  a background app receive notification for that?